# MySQL column with multiple items per column. How to retrive each?

Tags: php, mysql

I've a column in a database containing the names of screenshots related to that item. There can be 0 - 4 screenshots and they're stored in a text field like:

```
screenshot2-0.jpg;screenshot2-1.jpg;screenshot2-2.jpg;screenshot2-3.jpg
```

How can I extract them one by one with PHP, so I can echo each picture on the website?

---

Thanks! Thought it was much more complex. The working code:

```
<?php $arr = explode(';',$model->screenshot);
foreach($arr as $val) {
echo '<a href="http://www.website.dk/upload/';
echo $val; 
echo '" title="Se skærmbilledet i fuld størrelse ved at klikke her" target="_blank"</a>';
echo '<img src="http://www.website.dk/upload/';
echo $val; 
echo '" width="180" align="left" alt="Screenshot af';
echo $model->dk_name;
echo '"></a></td>'; 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$arr = explode(';','screenshot2-0.jpg;screenshot2-1.jpg;screenshot2-2.jpg;screenshot2-3.jpg');
foreach($arr as $val)
  echo $val;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a block around all the statements to repeat in the foreach

```
<?php $arr = explode(';',$model->screenshot);
foreach($arr as $val) {
    echo '<a href="http://www.website.dk/upload/';
    echo $val; 
    echo '" title="Se skærmbilledet i fuld størrelse ved at klikke her" target="_blank"</a>';
    echo '<img src="http://www.website.dk/upload/';
    echo $val; 
    echo '" width="180" align="left" alt="Screenshot af';
    echo $model->dk_name;
    echo '"></a></td>'; 
}

?>
```